# Push files from server to clients once

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp

We have gotten into a sort of predicament. We have set up a temporary training environment. Two domains with roughly 100 clients in each. Part of the training is using a map application on the client. The application is supposed to fetch the map from a map server. However, we have now noticed that the map server software can't handle that many users at the same time. We have been in contact with the software manufacturer and they say they can't fix anything in time for the training. Our backup plan is to copy the map files (roughly 11 GB) to each and every client. This has been tried and tested and works well. However, we are trying to find a way to do this efficiently. As it is now, copy+paste on each client is what we will do if we can't find a better solution.

Is there a way to copy the map files only once, like say at the next reboot or such? It doesn't have to be fancy or even lasting. We just want 11 GB of data distributed to 2 x 100 clients once and then we're happy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long are you giving for the copy to be completed?  Doing things at the next reboot is fine as long as you are giving the copy a sufficient amount of time to complete.  Also, I believe you will want to PULL the data and not push.  Final note, this is going to put a fairly hefty load on the network unless your source(s) are quick and located on quick network segments.  I'd hate to be copying this over a 10 MBit link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could he done simply in a login or startup script. Just check for the existence of the map file. If it is already there, don't do anything. If it is missing, have the clients wait a random amount of time (to reduce load on the server), then download the file.

Comment: Ty for the answer. After a meeting we decided that eventhough inefficient, manually copying would still be done since we have to do other thing on each client anyway. Still, thanks for the answer.